# Asp.Net Mvc and Win32 dll that is not designed for multithreading

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, com, thread-safety, mta

I need to build a web application (MVC) that uses a third-party win32 dll as gateway for all business logic (contains logon-mechanism, functions and maintains some state). 
This dll is not designed for multithreading. In an MTA scenario, the dll stumbles after a certain time. 
The recommended solution is to run ASP.NET MVC in ASP-Classic Mode (STA using an Asp-CompatHandler). I tried this with success - everything runs stable.
The probblem is, there will be a lot concurrent users and some of the function calls takes some seconds (up to 10 secodns!). This will get horrible if all users block each other.
What would be the best approach to minimize the blocking-effects within the same application? Say only ten users should block each other?

It would be nice if:
...the web runs in MTA
...the web is just deployed once
...everything runs within the same process

Can anyone give me some advice for a good concept solving this?

Thank you! Martin

**Update - Found a Solution:**
Thanks to the "Smart Thread Pool" from Ami Bar I could accomplish the behavior I was looking for (easily). I implemented a worker concept (a specific amout of users share a worker and block each other in this worker), and for each worker, I have now my own thread pool instance with a max and min number of one thread. Well, it's not the idea of a thread pool, but it makes it very easy to handle the work-items and it also has some nice other features. The web application is running on MTA now. 
I'm going to prepare some load tests to see if its stable over hours. 
see here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7933/Smart-Thread-Pool

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple, although I don't think you will like much: you cannot use something that is not designed to be used in a multithreaded environment in a multithreaded environment.

2 possibilities:

- Live with STA
- Replace the single threaded COM object with something that is intended to be used in a web application

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if the dll is not designed to be used with parallel requests, you cannot use it with parallel requests.

The only solution I see for you to increase the number of concurrent users without having the application running parallely is to have multiple instances of the application running at the same time, with maybe a load balancer in front of them to dispatch the queries.